# Sympy in Jupyter Notebook - Derivative Notation and Raw Latex

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sympy, mathjax

I'm new to notebooks and sympy. I have three questions. The notebook can be [viewed here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8293ad8ff6b6300df34be12d6dfbc478).

- Is there any way to change the derivative notation? It would be nice if it were a little more compact in the output.
- Is that `\rightarrowx` a bug?
- Is there any way to get the raw LaTeX string? e.g. `$f(x_0)^{2*x}$`

Answer (score 2):

- I don't know. (edit: it seems not. Here is the implementation https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/printing/latex.py#L567 )
- Yes, it is a bug. There should be a space between `\rightarrow` and `x_0`. (edit: it is fixed in the git version https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10836)
- Right-click -> Show Math As -> TeX Commands.